# How add new input to for and update value from database with ajax

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, forms

i have a database Included 3 columns " name " , " barcode " , " price " and have a form like blow :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwHIw.jpg

i want when user fill the barcode input and press " Enter " key 
do form like below pic :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPuXv.jpg

and the input names have be like blow :

```html
<HTML> 
  <form action="do.php" method="Post">
    name : <input name="name[]" type="text" />
    barcode: <input name="barcode[]" type="text" />
    price : <input name="price[]" type="text" />
  </form>
</HTML>
```

--- Update 1 ---

1. Jquery Source

   ```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#text").keyup(function(){
      var key = $("#text").val();
      var active = true;
      $.post("search.php",{key:key,active:active},function(data){
       $("#result").html(data);
      });
     });
       });
   </script>
   ```

```html
<?php
include "config/connect.php";
 if(isset($_post["active"]) && $_post["key"])
 {
  $key = $_post["key"];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_list` WHERE `barcode` LIKE :title ";
  $result = $connect->prepare($sql);
  $k = "%".$key."%";
  $result->bindParam(":title",$k); // ----> i have a error here ! <----
  if($result->execute())
  {
   if($result->rowCount()>0)
   {
    while($rows=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
     echo $rows["name"]."<hr />";
                    echo $rows["barcode"]."<hr />";
                    echo $rows["price"]."<hr />";
    }
   }
   else
   {
    echo "i can't fount anything . please try another barcode";
   }
  }
  
  
 }
?>
```

How echo result in a new inputs ?!
how Fix error ?!
what is problem ?!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some PHP code (since you tagged PHP)? Even if someone were to try to write all this code for you, they don't know your table structure (in MySQL).

Comment: I have a simple database . " id " is primary and A_I , "name" is text , "barcode" is text (cuz some codes have spaceb) and "price" is number.

Answer (score 0):

Add more information here. Show what you have already written in PHP.. You tagged php and such, but what you are asking for is lots of basic info on the web..

Show us how far you are with coding, then we can help. Without you doing anything except html code, people here aren't going to help u.. no offense.

Comment: i add Jquery and PHP Source but this sources doesn't work :(

Comment: You are grabbing the value of an ID called text, but no input of yours has an id text.. You are actually grabbing the type.. you should add an id="" to your line which you want to filter on key up. So for example if ur barcode has to be automatically updated on typing, you should add an id="barcode" to the input line, and in your jQuery code you should change the #text into #barcode then it grabs the value of that field.